# Literal control not updating javascript properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-visualization

I am dynamically generating a block of javascript in my page that ends up looking like this:

```
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart']});

function drawincomingCalls() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Call Type', 'Call Amount'],
        ['Voicemail', 12],
        ['Live Transfer', 23]
    ]);
    var options = {
        title: 'Incoming Calls',
        pieHole: 0.4
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('incomingCallsChart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    console.log(data);
}
</script>
```

This is generated by retrieving information from a SQL database and then setting a `literal` control's text property (which is within an `UpdatePanel` set to always update) to this script.

From there, I call `drawincomingCalls()` via `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`; I also do this on page load when `IsPostBack` is `true`.

This works fine; but when I change my 'date range' controls to cause a post-back and in turn regenerate the script, nothing changes. The old chart is rendered. I know that the script is regenerating fine because if I create a second `literal` control and copy everything I'm doing but without the `<script>` tag, I can read the changes in plain text and see that the values have indeed changed.

As seen in the snippet, I've logged `data` to the console, and it does not change either.

Again: Doing the *same thing* to two different literals (one with `<script>` tags and one without), one is updating fine while the actual script is not.

If I run the raw javascript through Chrome console, it updates correctly.

Is there something blatant I'm missing here?

Comment: hope this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336948/google-visualization-is-small-inside-ajax-control-toolkit-tab-control

 your code only works for the first time. you have to make it aware of ajax calls. like regenerating the google chart on ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Google the client-side `pageLoad()` Javascript method that ASP.NET Ajax creates for you - this will get triggered on a partial postback, so put your code to (re)generate the chart in there.